# Replace selected content in the ckEditor with new content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor ver.3.6 in my MVC Application.

My requirement is to update the selected text with new text in the ckEditor. I could find out the method editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();  for getting selected text from the editor. I need to add some tag with the selected text when a toolbar button is pressed and update the selected content using javascript.

For Example :

Content in the ckEditor is

```
 <span>Edit content in the editor</span>
```

and I have selected the word “editor” from ckEditor. I have to update the selected word “editor” with “ckEditor” using javascript code.

Please suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me from the docs as the following would work (untested):

```
editor.insertText("ckEditor");
```

Comment: Also, the replaced element should be selected.     editor.getSelection().selectElement(element);

Comment: @efeyc how do you get 'element'?

Answer (score 4):

Use this function in the onclick event of a button.

```
function Replace()
 {
  //after selecting the text in the editor
  //get text to replace;    
  var repStr=$("#repTxt").val();        
  editor.insertHtml(repStr);    
 }
```

Cheers
Sunil Raj

Answer (score 1):

Both `editor.insertText()` and `editor.insertHtml()` should work, but you have to make sure the editor is ready before you attempt to update the text:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');

editor.on('instanceReady', function(){
    editor.insertHtml('...');
});
```